# How to resize Qr image

Tags: .net, qr-code

I want to resize Generated QR image in terms of height and width. How can i do it?

My code is as below:

```
MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder qe = new MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder();
qe.QRCodeEncodeMode = QRCodeEncoder.ENCODE_MODE.BYTE;
qe.QRCodeErrorCorrect = QRCodeEncoder.ERROR_CORRECTION.L;
qe.QRCodeVersion = qrlevel;
System.Drawing.Bitmap bm = qe.Encode(Data_TO_Encode);
```

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not hugely familiar with `MessagingToolkit` but you can always just resize the `Bitmap`.

Using the below and adding your own `height` and `weight`:

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap((Image)qe.Encode(Data_TO_Encode), new Size(width, height));
```

BUT QR codes are recommended for certain sizes for the different levels. Increasing the size isn't usually necessary. AND when resizing the `Bitmap` it ***may*** introduce some artefacts that could corrupt the QR data. But it's an option if you *really* need it resized and you don't care about possible corruption.

**UPDATE**

You can also increase the level and provide more data, but it will still work and would be larger. Apart from that, I don't know if there is any other functionality in the `MessagingToolkit` that can help with this, but I also don't know if there should be. Export it in the default/recommended size. Worst case scenario load it into a graphics program and resizing in there, using no interpolation, this will keep the sharp edges required. Or you can look up scaling algorithms that you could apply to the `Bitmap` (I think nearest neighbour is one you could use.)

But this is all a bit overkill for just this. Unless there is a drastic need for the resized image I would just leave it.

Comment: I'm known about the bitmap image resizing, but it corrupts the QR data, as you mentioned.
Thanks anyways.

I just wanted to know if there is available any other library for QR code generation which provides the resizing functionality.